# Getting error could not determine data type of parameter $2 while putting $2 in CONCAT()

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to update story column using the CONCAT function in psql, but somehow keep getting error saying it could not determine data type of parameter $2. Where did I do wrong?

```
router.put('/:id', (req,res) => {
    db.query(`UPDATE stories SET story = CONCAT(story, $2) WHERE id = $1`,[req.params.id, 'text'])
      .then(response => {
        res.json({contribution:req.body.contribution_data, id:req.params.id});
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('Edit story error', err.message));
  });
```

## Update May, 06, 2021

Thanks for the suggestion @Ayzrian

I did the PREPARE statement as suggested, but now I got a different error:

> "error cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement"

I did basically the same format as suggested in the documentation:

```js
router.put("/:id", (req, res) => {

    db.query(
      `
     PREPARE testStory (int, text ) AS UPDATE stories SET story = CONCAT(story, $2) WHERE id = $1;
     EXECUTE testStory ($1, $2);`,
      [req.params.id, "text"]
    )
```

## Update Solution

Turns out I can set the data type by doing the ::text after the paramterized value($1 in this case). Here's the solution code:

```
db.query(
      `
     UPDATE stories
     SET story = CONCAT(story, $1::text)
     WHERE id = $2;
     `,
      ["testinggg", req.params.id]
    )
```

Thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I can set the data type by doing the ::text after the paramterized value($1 in this case). Here's the solution code:

```
db.query(
      `
     UPDATE stories
     SET story = CONCAT(story, $1::text)
     WHERE id = $2;
     `,
      ["testinggg", req.params.id]
    )
```

Thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the value that you can insert into `CONCAT` can have a different data type, because of that Postgres cannot define the datatype of the field you will be inserted from the context where you are using it.
I believe that you may want to use the full `PREPARE` statement to specify the data type of argument.

```
 db.query(`
     PREPARE test (int, text ) AS UPDATE stories SET story = CONCAT(story, $2) WHERE id = $1; 
     EXECUTE test ($1, $2);`,
     [req.params.id, 'text']
)
```

Please have a look at the doc https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-prepare.html